# Do I need to use a WP8-specific Azure SDK?

Tags: windows-8, sdk, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, azure-mobile-services

At this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/01/09/new-windows-azure-mobile-services-getting-started-content.aspx I see that there are separate Azure SDKs for Windows Store and 
Windows Phone 8.

In my app suite (a Windows Store app and a complementary WP8 app), I'm currently using only the 
Windows Store SDK - I haven't downloaded/installed the WP8-specific Azure SDK. Do I need to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same download for WP8 and Windows 8; of course, iOS is completely different, hence the calling out of different SDKs.